# Is there an alternative adjective to 'written' with an -al suffix?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm ideally looking for a single word adjective with an -al suffix. i.e. similar to 'verbal', and 'visual' but that relates to written communications rather than spoken or illustrative communications. Does such a word exist?

I'm trying to create a bit of wordplay about different communication methods.

Thank you!

Comment: *verbal* is more ambiguous than *oral* for spoken communications, as it can simply mean using words

Comment: @Henry _oral_ can mean spoken, by mouth, or pertaining to the mouth, but never means simply using (unspoken) words.

Comment: @JohnFactorial: I do not think we disagree

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One normally uses **textual** to indicate that something is written, for text is normally written.

Answer (score 4):

You could try 'scribal' - of or relating to a scribe... 'Scriptal' does not, unfortunately, seem to exist!

Comment: Adding a source for the meaning of *scribal* would strengthen this answer.

Comment: From Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary (10th ed.)

Answer (score 3):

Literal means 'pertaining to letters of the alphabet.'

Comment: And of course ***alphabetical***

Comment: Two completely correct answers that would utterly mislead the reader if used. :-)

Comment: @DJClayworth true! Everyone uses 'literal' in the figurative sense now, to mean 'in actual fact'. :)

Comment: Most people use 'literally' to mean 'metaphorically' :-)

Comment: @DJClayworth: That's a common misconception. No one on Earth uses "literally" to mean "metaphorically". If someone says "literally drowning in red tape", they may be misusing the word "literally", but they're obviously not aiming for "metaphorically drowning in red tape".

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of 'literally' in that sentence? 'Metaphorically' would fit right in.

Comment: 'Literally' is usually used metaphorically, to mean 'not metaphorically'. Some people use 'literally' metaphorically, to mean 'metaphorically'. Almost no-one uses 'literally' literally, to mean 'about the alphabet'. Clear? :) http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2013/11/metaphors?fsrc=scn/tw/te/bl/ed/metaphorstheimpossibilityofbeingliteral

Comment: @DJClayworth: It's just an intensifier, like *really* or *seriously* or *thoroughly*. "Metaphorically" does *not* fit there, because no sane person would feel the need to put it there (except as a joke).

Comment: @SteveCooper: Clear, but mistaken. People sometimes use *literally* even when they don't actually mean that something is literally true, but they never use *literally* **to mean** that something is not literally true.

Comment: This may be confusing to many, but to a programmer it might actually work. Think of *string literals* - strings, *written out* in the code.

Comment: @ruakh not so. People have used 'literally' as an intensifier since the nineteenth century, and often use it with metaphors. http://www.theguardian.com/politics/reality-check-with-polly-curtis/2012/mar/12/reality-check-literally-wrong-use-word

Comment: @SteveCooper: Right, except that I'm not sure why you say "not so". Exactly so: people often use *literally*, with metaphors, as an intensifier; but they never use it to mean *metaphorically*. (Note that *metaphorically* is *not* used as an intensifier.)

Comment: Ah, yeah! We agree! 'Literally' intensifies; the metaphor that follows is the figure of speech. So people say 'literally specific-thing-X' to mean 'metaphorically large like X'. 'Literally 500 years old' means 'very old,' and the 'literally' negates the specific claim.

Comment: @SteveCooper: No, we don't agree. "Literally 500 years old" means "very old", just as "500 years old" does. The "literally" doesn't negate the specific claim, any more than the lack of it would.